# Loop through list of tuples, call elements independently

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples:

```
Months = [('2011-01-01', '2011-02-01'), ('2011-02-01', '2011-03-01'), ('2011-03-01', '2011-04-01'), ...]
```

I would like to define a function that loops through the list, and calls the elements of the tuple independently.  For example:

```
def function(list):
    print """
    Start %s
    End %s
    """ % list
```

I would them do something like:

```
for tuple in months:
    function(tuple)
```

Obviously I have a problem as I have two %s's but only one argument.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make `lst` a tuple, so call `function` for each element in your `Months` list:

```
for start_end in Months:
    func(start_end)
```

and make your string use *three* quotes:

```
def func(tup):
    print """
    Start %s
    End %s
    """ % tup
```

String formatting supports passing in a tuple defined in a variable, as long as it has the correct length:

```
>>> tup = ('2011-01-01', '2011-02-01')
>>> print """
...     Start %s
...     End %s
...     """ % tup

    Start 2011-01-01
    End 2011-02-01
```

Alternatively, use `str.format()` to format:

```
def func(tup):
    print """
    Start {0[0]}
    End {0[0]}
    """.format(tup)
```

You can also use tuple unpacking; assign each tuple in the list to *two* variables in the loop:

```
for start, end in Months:
    print 'Start {}\nEnd'.format(start, end)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for date1, date2 in Months:
    print """"
    Start %s
    End %s
    """" % (date1, date2)
```